# multiprocessing hangs curses in python

Tags: python, curses

hope you can help. I try to write a terminal application using python and curses and for one job I'm forced to use multiprocessing.

The problem I faced is that no matter what I do, curses hangs right after I start a multiprocess `p1` and I do not see "it works" string. If, however, I remove loop from method `foo`, it works, or if I put `{print "aaa"}` in to `foo()` method, terminal is spammed with strings.

In other words, curses is inactive until process finishes though it should be opposit. How can I avoid it?

```
import time
import math
import sys
import curses
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

sen1= Value('f',0)

def foo():
    while(True):
        sen.value = 1

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
stdscr.border(0)
stdscr.addstr(12, 25, "Python curses in action!")
stdscr.refresh()
p1 = Process(target=foo())
p1.start()
while true:
    stdscr.addstr(1,1,"it works" !!)
```

Answer (score 4):

When you start a process (or a thread), the target needs to be a *reference* to the function you want to run.

When you write this:

```
p1 = Process(target=foo())
```

You're telling `Process` that the target should be the *result* of executing `foo`, not `foo` itself.
Try this instead:

```
p1 = Process(target=foo)  # do not call foo
```

In other words, you're getting an infinite loop from the `while True` in `foo` on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that what you saw as "hang" might also be a missing curses update? sapi's answer does not actually remove the "hang" for me, I still don't see the "it works!!"...

Here's my iteration on your code that works better for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import curses
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

shared_mem = Value('i', 1)

def incrementor():
    while shared_mem.value > 0:
        shared_mem.value += 1
        time.sleep(0.001)

screen = curses.initscr()

curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
screen.keypad(1)

screen.border(0)
screen.addstr(12, 20, "Parent: {}!".format(shared_mem.value))

p1 = Process(target=incrementor)
p1.start()

while True:
    # delay in tenths of seconds
    curses.halfdelay(5)

    screen.addstr(12, 28, "{}!".format(shared_mem.value))

    event = screen.getch()
    if event == ord("q"):
        shared_mem.value = 0
        break

curses.endwin()
```

You will see that the sub-process increments the value while the main program just refreshes the screen every half second. You can play around with the delays to get a feeling for what's going on.

Of course, alternatively, you can just add a line with `stdscr.refresh()` in your while loop at the end of the main process. That, together with sapi's fix, will make your program "not hang", too.